# Testing change in categories?

Tags: proportion

I hope that someone will be willing to help me with the following question. I have data on the numbers of hours participants spent in 6 programs over 2 years. I have already tested whether the number of hours increased over time, but I also want to know whether the proportion of time spent in each of the programs changed over time. 
Eg. Program1/Time1 = 2920 hrs/10000hrs; Program1/Time 2 =3200/12000; Program2/Time1 = 4200/10000; Program2/Time2 = 3800/12000, etc.

Would a 2 sample z test for proportion change on each program (perhaps with Bonferoni correction) be appropriate? And/or is there another test(s) That I should be using? Any help would be much appreciated! I am comfortable with SPSS and am starting to learn R, if that makes a difference...

Comment: The nature of your data are not yet clear. Are you saying that at time 1 a total of 10000 hours were spent and of those, 2920 were in program 1 and 4200 in program 2, etc.?  If that's the case, why does it look like the total for time 2 is both 10000 hours and 12000 hours?

Comment: Oops! Thanks for offering me the opportunity to correct! Your first understanding was correct; I meant for the total hours in Time 1 to be 10000 and Time 2 to be 12000; I have now edited.

Answer (score 0):

Proportion test should be adequate here. prop.test function in R will calculate that. 
I don't think you need a multiple hypothesis testing correction here. You only doing a few tests. And in any case  Bonferoni is a very conservative correction. A Benjamini-Hochberg FDR is often a better choice.